# ASP.NET MVC Deployment Referencing Development Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC 3 application using Visual Studio 2010's "Publish Web" option (build/Publish App). This generates deployment/bin, deployment/scripts, deployment/views etc.

I loaded these resulting deployment files/folders to a web server running IIS 6. Afterwards, everything seemed to run just fine on this web server.

I then started to make new updates, just to my local environment. After doing that, the deployed version of the site stopped working. I looked at the stack trace and the web server seemed to be referencing controllers.cs from my local environment, as opposed to the dll's in the bin directory on the web server.

Is there something else I need to do before deployment to tell the web server to use it's own bin files as opposed to files on my development environment?

BTW both my development machine and the web server live on the same network.

**Update:**

Another thing that made me suspect that the web server was referencing my local dev environment was that when a new user tried to access the application she got an IOFileNotFoundException in regards to a reference to "Interop.ActiveDs.dll". The stack trace mentioned my_local_path/Interop.ActiveDs.dll. This file was in fact not on the web server so I added it and then her error went away. The Odd thing was that all other users before her did not recieve an error about this missing reference.

Comment: I'm not sure it MVC apps works fine on the IIS6 natively. Probably you will need to do some adjustments to get it working at IIS6. Look this link: http://www.codefrenzy.net/2011/10/19/deploying-asp-net-mvc-3-to-iis-6/

Comment: When you say "seems to be referencing..." do you mean a stack trace shows your local path?  That's because when assemblies are compiled, they include the local path in the .pdb files so you can go back and look at the source code.

Comment: Felipe, I actually followed those steps earlier and thats how I finally got MVC 3 to run on IIS.

Comment: Mystere, Yes the stack traces do show my local path but I do have the .pdb files included in the bin directory. Any guesses?